# Why does using ./filename from within .jar write to user folder?

Tags: java, macos, jar, filepath

I have a project with the following file structure:

```
Project
 |
 +-- storage.bin
 |    
 +-- myfile.jar
```

In myfile.jar I have the lines of code:

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("./storage.bin"));
out.writeObject(listOfObjects);
out.close();
```

I intended to have this write to the storage.bin file in the project directory but rather it creates and writes to a storage.bin file in my user directory. How can I create the intended function?

note: I am using a mac, and the overall project structure is  that of a mac application

Comment: Say I take your `myfile.jar`, copy it to my computer, and run it. Where should it write `listOfObjects` to? Why?

Comment: `./` is specify the "current" or "working" directory, which appears to be the user directory.  If you bundle the App as a "app bundle" on Mac, the "working" directory seems to (at least from my testing) be the user's home directory.  This is why you should focus putting configuration/persistent data in well known locations, like `~/Library/Application Support/{You app's name}`, then it doesn't matter

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis to the storage.bin file in the same directory as the .jar

Comment: use class path to load/handle resources in the project?

Comment: Relative paths (like those that start with `./`) are relative to the process's working directory. By default, that's inherited from the parent process. It has *nothing whatsoever* to do with the location of the executable.

Answer (score -1):

`./` is represents the work path.
1.
`.../Project/` Run Java in the path.
2.

````java
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(".../Project/storage.bin"));```
````